# How can I determine whether my Internet is failing because of my modem, router, or ISP?

Tags: router, internet, internet-connection, cable-modem

I have one of the worst ISPs (Comcast) ... but they have a monopoly and I'm stuck with them.  Things do work fine most of the time, but far too often my internet will just cut out for no reason.  Sometimes rebooting my modem/router helps, sometimes it doesn't (but then everything works a little while later).

I very strongly *suspect* the problem is my ISP, but if I call them up and say as much, they claim all they can do is send out a technician, and if it's my equipment's fault I'll get billed $100+ for the visit.

My question is, how can I prove to myself (and Comcast) that it isn't my equipment (or if it is my equipment, how can I tell whether it's the modem or router, so I know which to replace)?

**EDIT:** Someone closed this as unclear, but I can't fathom why!  My internet stops working periodically: how do I tell which component (of the three responsible: modem, router, ISP) is the root cause ... what's confusing about that?

Comment: you can discount the router by jacking directly into the modem, but telling whether a problem is in your cabling to the local infrastructure, or a bad modem, or the ISPs management practices is pretty difficult. a technician should be ablve to tell at least if the cabling is performing as expected though, so they can probably tell the diff between the modem and the lines.

Comment: What model is your modem? What about your router? You can sometimes go into your modem's status page and view signal levels coming in over coax. If the signal is good, then it's likely not their problem. You can also directly connect a PC to the modem and bypass the router. That way, you can see if your router was causing an issue.

Comment: I have a Motorola MB7420 modem and an Asus RT-N56U router.  I can navigate to the router, but not when the Internet is out (which is odd; you'd think I could connect to the router even when the Internet is down; not sure if that means the route is the problem, or just that it's lame).  I don't think I can browse to the modem.  It's difficult (physically) to connect directly to the modem, but I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy test is to jack straight into the modem and then run a continuous ping to an address. Using google's DNS address is usually a good indicator.

Open command prompt and run `ping 8.8.8.8 /t` and let it run to see how many times you get a "request timed out" alert. Then, after you find failure or success with that, add your router back into the mix and do the same thing.